# QML ValueAxis can't find a way to change color of label

Tags: qml, qtcharts

In the ValueAxis [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-valueaxis.html) I can't seem to find a property to change the color of the title which is by default black. I want to change it to white.

Answer (score 4):

You can use html formatting when setting the title of the axis.

```
titleText: "<font color='white'>YourTitle</font>"
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out you can simply set the titleBrush of your axis to a color directly in QML even though it's not in the documentation. Unlike the other answers this allows me to do it dynamically, with the color not necessarily a hard coded string
This is how I do it for my x axis:

```
DateTimeAxis
{
    id: timeAxis
    format: "hh:mm:ss"
    color: "white"
    labelsColor: color
    gridLineColor: color
    minorGridLineColor: color
    titleBrush: color
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function in C++ that you can call from QML by marking it as `Q_INVOKABLE` like so:

In your header file:

```
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE QBrush titleBrush() const;
```

In your class file:

```
QBrush ChartStyler::titleBrush() const
{
    return QBrush(Qt::white);
}
```

Then you can call this in your QML:

```
import MyCoolProgram.ChartStyler 1.0

ChartStyler {
    id: chartStyler
    ...
    ValueAxis {
        titleText: "My X Axis"
        titleBrush: chartStyler.titleBrush()
    }
    ...
}
```

If you don't already have a class you can access from QML, you'll need to register `ChartStyler` (in `main.cpp` for example)

```
 qmlRegisterType<ChartStyler>("MyCoolProgram.ChartStyler", 1, 0, "ChartStyler");
```